# Embedded Resources(resx) are giving me trouble- memory consumption

Tags: c#, memory

Consider the following class file that I use to access a .resx that contains multiple sound files with different file sizes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace Resources
{
 public class ResManager
 {

    public static void SoundCopy(String ResourceName, String Dest)
    {
        try
        {
            var rm = Resources.Sounds.ResourceManager;
            var resStream = rm.GetStream(ResourceName);

            if (!File.Exists(Dest))
            {
                File.Create(Dest).Close();
            }
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Dest, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

            CopyStream(resStream, fs);

            resStream.Close();
            resStream = null;

            fs.Close();
            fs = null;

            rm.ReleaseAllResources();
            rm = null;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // nothlng
        }

    } // S copy();

    private static void CopyStream(Stream from, Stream to)
    {
        int bufSize = 1024, count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        count = from.Read(buffer, 0, bufSize);
        while (count > 0)
        {
           // StackOverflow -- working set raises here
            to.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            count = from.Read(buffer, 0, bufSize);
        } 

        // clean up
        buffer = null;
    } // c str()


 } //class
} //namespace
```

Whatever I copy a different file to the filesystem, I noticed that the program keeps a certain Working Set permanently allocated after i do that, but copying the same file for more than 2 times doesn't.

I am trying to keep my app efficient , i tried to make a duplicate class that needs to be instanciated to do this, then i gave it null value and i've waited 40 minutes to see if the GC did something, but nope.

Normally my app runs at 29 MB working set jumping every 10 s to 37~ MB. After I copied 3 files to temp folder, the working set raised at 133 MB, and it stayed at that during my 40 minute pause.

Additional note: I am targetting .NET 2.0

Comment: GC has nothing to do with this, embedded resources are mapped into the address space with a memory mapped file.  Working set just doesn't mean that much on modern machines, they have too much RAM to convince the OS to unmap the virtual memory pages again.  The point is not the "pause", you have to use other expensive programs that need a lot of RAM.  Given the rather low odds that this kind of code is frequently used, you'd be much better off with a file instead of an embedded resource.  You'll use 81 KB of RAM instead of 100 MB.  Or just not worry about it and let the OS do its job.

Comment: I changed my code so that if the file already exists there won't be need to get it from embedded resources , but i'll leave it open , i'm curious if there is a way :)